# Change value of property of all objects except in one

Tags: javascript

I have an array of the candidacies:

```
candidacies = service.getCandidacies();
```

where each candidacy is an object such as:

```
{ id: 1, isHired: true }, 
{ id: 4, isHired: false }, 
{ id: 8, isHired: false }
```

I need to set all candidacies in the list with `isHired = false` and the one with `id = 4` as `isHired = true`. I have more objects in the array. These are one example.

I tried to use the map function but not sure how to use it or if is even possible:

```
  candidacies = candidacies.map(function(x) {

  });
```

But I am not sure how or if is even possible ...

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original objects or return an array of new objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your objects are in an array as such:

```
candidacies = [
  { id: 1, isHired: true }, 
  { id: 4, isHired: false }, 
  { id: 8, isHired: false }
]
```

Then the map would look like:

```
candidacies = candidacies.map(function(candidate, index) {
  candidate.isHired = candidate.id === 4; 
  return candidate;
})
```

Comment: The ternary operator is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using your own stub, the easiest approach is to just add a logical test:

```
candidacies = candidacies.map(function(x) {
    x.isHired = x.id === 4;
    return x;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` for this (as you are changing the variable anyway):

```js
var candidacies = [{ id: 1, isHired: true }, 
                   { id: 4, isHired: false }, 
                   { id: 8, isHired: false }];

candidacies.forEach(function(candidacy) {
  candidacy.isHired = (candidacy.id === 4);
});

console.log(candidacies);
```

If you really want to use `map` (which is good if you assign the result to another variable), you can do this:

```js
var candidacies = [{ id: 1, isHired: true }, 
                   { id: 4, isHired: false }, 
                   { id: 8, isHired: false }];

var newCandidacies = candidacies.map(function(candidacy) {
  return Object.assign({}, candidacy, { isHired: (candidacy.id === 4) });
});

console.log(newCandidacies);
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a question a student would ask, if that's the case we're not here to solve your homework for you. The map function iterates through an array and applies whatever `function()` you define. Either way you can run some `console.log(x)` to see how it might work. Best of luck.